# Backing up iPhone photos to iPad Mini on lengthy travel

Tags: backup, iphone, ipad

I will be purchasing an iPad mini for my iPhone to back up pictures (among other uses). 
I'll be traveling for approximately three months, and, as a traveler, I would say I don't take that many photographs. However, because of the length of my trip and because there's always the chance that I do take more photos, I'm worried if 16gb will be enough as my back up "hard drive."

Assuming the worst case scenario where I shoot HDR for all of my pictures, would the 16gb iPad mini be sufficient? If this question is too vague, then how many HDR photos could I hold with 16gb (I can't find this information elsewhere)?

Comment: Are you sure that even with using the camera connection kit - that you can back them up to the iPad?  I'd be more inclined to use Photostream - it'll back up every pic you take to the cloud.  If you have iPhoto or Aperture on a mac you can then download them at home.

Comment: Wait until you hit a WIFI spot and throw the shots up to iCloud. You get 5gb for free there. Also, you could look at Dropbox.

Comment: @Mike Well I wanted some redundancies, I was going to back them up to the cloud (not sure how to do this yet), and also back them up to my iPad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can fill 16GB at all with iPhone JPEGs even in a whole year of shooting like crazy, but you are better off doing some simple maths: take a look at the average size of your files (I assume than the iPhone totally sucks giving the user such information, so you would have to copy the files to a proper PC), make an estimation of how many pictures per day are you going to take, multiply that but the number of days and see if that's greater than the space you have available (and remember that 16GB does not mean that all of them are accessible by the user!).

Answer (score 1):

16 GB is enough for a very large number of low megapixel JPEG images (probably over ten thousand), however there are a lot of other factors involved, such as how else you will use the iPad and how much space that will consume.  There is also the question of security of the backup as an iPad is an even higher theft risk than the iPhone.

Why not simply get an iPhone/SD Card adapter?  They plug in to the dock connection and you could then load your images off to SD cards which are cheap and won't consume space on your iPad.

If you'll have a data connection, there are also online options you could use for storage that wouldn't even require you to physically bring things with you.

An iPad doesn't really make much sense as a backup device compared to the other options available.

Comment: Without a jailbreak, you can't copy to the SD card from an iPad.

Comment: JoanneC: wow, that makes me very sad... and very happy I haven't used an iCrap device since the first generation iPod Touch.

Comment: There are other ways to do it, so it's not really that big an issue. I generally use wireless options, capacities are massively bigger as a result and that's a factor with a D800.